# body перебирать классы от скролла

Tags: jquery

сайт изначально с черным фоном когда скролишь 1000px нужно менять фон сайта на белый, но когда возвращаешься в к первому блок и начинаешь скролить опять вниз нужно что бы фон был черный и так каждый раз приключалось
допустим первый раз я прокрутил и body добавился класс color-white, поднялся вверх к началу сайта, класс color-white пропал, начал скролить опять и добавился класс color-black, и так переключать

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
var height = $(window).scrollTop();
if(height > 1000){
$('body').addClass('color-white');
} else{

$('body').removeClass('');
}
});
```

```css
body {min-height:3000px;background-color:#000;}
body.color-white {background-color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Comment: $('body').removeClass('color-white');
Не?)

Comment: ну он уберет белый цвет а при прокрутки вниз опять добавит

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли указать класс, который убираете. `$('body').removeClass('color-white');`

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
var height = $(window).scrollTop();
if(height > 1000){
$('body').addClass('color-white');
} else{

$('body').removeClass('color-white');
}
});
```

```css
body {min-height:3000px;background-color:#000;}
body.color-white {background-color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Comment: он туда сюда меняет белый фон, я это и сам могу, но проблема не в этом

Comment: Так в чём проблема тогда?)

Comment: вы суть вопроса поняли? нужно что бы когда прокрутил вниз было белым, поднялся к первому блоку сайт стал черным, опять поднялся внизу и начал опускаться стал белым , и так переключать

Comment: Объясните тогда более нормально.

Comment: а что не понятно?

Comment: "но когда возвращаешься в к первому блок и начинаешь скролить опять вниз нужно что бы фон был черный и так каждый раз приключалось" чёрный фон должен быть внизу?

Comment: речь идет о фоне body в целом все 3000px

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126538/discussion-between---and-usergames).